# How can i search in Github api?

Tags: git, github, github-api

I want to search in github api with my query.
For example:

```
  https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+sample
```

I want to convert this link to github api link.
How can i do this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The [API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-issues) is pretty clear:

> ### Search issues
>
> Find issues by state and keyword. (This method returns up to 100 results [per page](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination).)
>
> ```
> GET /search/issues
> ```

I'm reformatting the parameters here, since Stack Overflow Markdown doesn't support tables:

> #### Parameters
>
> - `q`, a string: The search terms.
> - `sort`, a string: The sort field. Can be `comments`, `created`, or `updated`. Default: results are sorted by best match.
> - `order`, a string: The sort order if `sort` parameter is provided. One of `asc` or `desc`. Default: `desc`
>
> The `q` search term can also contain any combination of the supported issue search qualifiers:

I'll skip over most of these, but it looks like you may be interested in

> - `state` Filter issues based on whether they’re open or closed.

or

> - `is` Searches for items within repositories that match a certain state, such as `open`, `closed`, or `merged`

Note that this endpoint is only for Issues, so your `is:issue` parameter is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=sample+user:antirez+repo:redis+state:open
```

This returns a json document that contains a list of objects representing the issues that match the search criteria. However this returns a broader set of issues.

The difference between the result set you provided because the issue search via the GUI is only searching the comments. To get the exact result you get from the front-end page you need to add the `in:comments` restriction to the search, the url for that would look like this:

```
https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=sample+user:antirez+repo:redis+state:open+in:comments
```

You can browse the [GitHub API Documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/) and more specifically [this endpoint's documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-issues) for more details.

Let me know if you need any other clarification or if this was not quite you where looking for